# getting failed authentication error while upload blob using connection string contains both container name & sas token

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload a blob using below code using nuget package `<PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.14.1" />` where `connectionString` contains both container name (`my-container`) and SAS token,

`https://my-storage.blob.core.windows.net/my-container?sv=2018-03-28&sr=c&sig=DZSbKgaKd%2FjYQbYQf7eOAZ%2BVFSY1Rq2M7HIVXs%2F%2BPtA%3D&se=2023-02-12T04%3A08%3A07Z&sp=rcwl`

Code:

```
var blobClient = new BlobClient(new Uri(connectionString));
await using var fileStream = entry.Open();
await blobClient.UploadAsync(fileStream, true);
```

I am getting error,

> `AuthenticationFailed`Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

RequestId:5a7b1650-501e-001d-7ed2-3d2845000000
Time:2023-02-11T04:35:40.8903035ZSignature did not match. String to sign used was rcwl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code is failing is because you're trying to create an instance of `BlobClient` using a container SAS URL. What you need to do is create an instance of `BlobContainerClient` using the SAS URL and then create an instance of `BlobClient`.

Please try something like:

```
var blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(new Uri(connectionString));
var blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient("blobname");
await using var fileStream = entry.Open();
await blobClient.UploadAsync(fileStream, true);
```

Comment: yeah! Thanks Gaurav for point out the mistake :) I realize  the same :)